# Print a blank row after each row of the result of a dictionary created with a class. I print only the keys and not the values

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary, printing

This code, which works correctly, prints the results in a somewhat garbled way, because the content of each row is very long and because each row has no space with the following row. I would like to add space, i.e. an empty row, between each row with the key.

I tried so many ways to apply to `print(test)`, for example with: `* and sep="\n"`, with a `for` loop, with a `range`, with `+ "\n"`, with `join` and other ways. The problem is that I always get the same result: I get the print with the space, but just print some keys without the dictionary values (which are taken from a class). Maybe i need to add the space inside the code and not directly in print

Currently printing goes like this (all in the same row):

```
{'Vegas-New York ': Info_Match(championship='NHL', date=8.1, round=9, clock='15:00', scorehome=[0, 1, 1, 5], scoreaway=[0, 0, 0, 3],'Minnesota-Dallas': Info_Match(championship='NHL', date=8.1, round=9, clock='18:00', scorehome=[1, 2, 3 , 4], scoreaway=[0, 2, 2, 2]
```

I would like this output:

```
{'Vegas-New York ': Info_Match(championship='NHL', date=8.1, round=9, clock='15:00', scorehome=[0, 1, 1, 5], scoreaway=[0, 0, 0, 3],

'Minnesota-Dallas': Info_Match(championship='NHL', date=8.1, round=9, clock='18:00', scorehome=[ 1, 2, 3, 4], scoreaway=[0, 2, 2, 2]
```

Or, this:

```
{'Vegas-New York':
  Info_Match(championship='NHL', date=8.1, round=9, clock='15:00', scorehome=[0, 1, 1, 5], scoreaway=[0, 0, 0, 3],

'Minnesota-Dallas':
Info_Match(championship='NHL', date=8.1, round=9, clock='18:00', scorehome=[1, 2, 3, 4], scoreaway=[0, 2, 2, 2]
```

Code

```
@dataclass
class Info_Match:
    championship: str
    date: float
    round: int
    clock: str
    scorehome: list[int]
    scoreaway: list[int]

test = {}

db = cursor_test.execute("sql code")

for row in db.fetchall():
    if row[0] not in test:
        info = Info_Match(
                championship=row[1],
                date=row[2],
                round=row[3],
                clock=row[4],
                scorehome=list(),
                scoreaway=list())


        test[row[0]] = info
    test[row[0]].scorehome.append(row[5])

print(test)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have your dictionary (`test`), 
you could just iterate through it using **f-strings** to produce the desired output:

```
for k,v in test.items():
    print(f"{k}: {v}", end='\n\n')
```

#### Code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Info_Match:
    championship: str
    date: float
    round: int
    clock: str
    scorehome: list[int]
    scoreaway: list[int]
    
test = {'Vegas-New York': Info_Match(championship='NHL', date=8.1, round=9, clock='15:00', scorehome=[0, 1, 1, 5], scoreaway=[0, 0, 0, 3]),'Minnesota-Dallas': Info_Match(championship='NHL', date=8.1, round=9, clock='18:00', scorehome=[1, 2, 3 , 4], scoreaway=[0, 2, 2, 2])}

for k,v in test.items():
    print(f"{k}: {v}", end='\n\n')
```

#### Output:

```
Vegas-New York: Info_Match(championship='NHL', date=8.1, round=9, clock='15:00', scorehome=[0, 1, 1, 5], scoreaway=[0, 0, 0, 3])

Minnesota-Dallas: Info_Match(championship='NHL', date=8.1, round=9, clock='18:00', scorehome=[1, 2, 3, 4], scoreaway=[0, 2, 2, 2])
```

---

#### Note:

To print your second option: you could use:

```
for k,v in test.items():
    print(f"{k}:\n{v}", end='\n\n')
```

##### Output:

```
Vegas-New York:
Info_Match(championship='NHL', date=8.1, round=9, clock='15:00', scorehome=[0, 1, 1, 5], scoreaway=[0, 0, 0, 3])

Minnesota-Dallas:
Info_Match(championship='NHL', date=8.1, round=9, clock='18:00', scorehome=[1, 2, 3, 4], scoreaway=[0, 2, 2, 2])
```

Comment: Thank you. And instead to print as per the second option of my question? How can I do? Thank you

Comment: Updated code to show second option